# Pandas.tseries.tools.normalize_date is deprecated for python 3, but I can't find the conversion?

Tags: python, pandas

I am on Windows 10 and running Miniconda 3.6.6. I am running the following command and getting the following error

```
C:\Users>python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pandas.tseries.tools import normalize_date
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.tseries.tools'
```

I already checked online but there doesn't seem to be any documentation for converting `pandas.tseries.tools` for Python 3. Could someone provide me with the updated code to work for Python 3?

I've already tried `from pandas.tslib import normalize_date` but `normalize_date` is not recognized.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html?

Comment: What version of pandas, and what code?

Comment: My pandas version is Version: 0.23.4, the code is above.

Comment: Huh, it might have been yanked out and thrown into Zipline? https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/pull/2086/files#diff-c20d00d3101fbeb7408be5ccc65c6032L65 EDIT: NM, it looks like the method I linked originally is the correct replacement, Zipline seems to have split from the pandas dependency or something for that functionality

Comment: I'm running an older version of zipline due to legacy code.